# program doesnt work if called from another folder

Tags: c, windows, command-line

In Command Prompt, this works: `whatever\folder> bezier.exe`

but this doesn't: `whatever> folder\bezier.exe`

My bezier program loads some settings from a local file, so I believe the problem is that the program thinks its directory is `whatever\` when it is actually `whatever\folder\`. I'm calling it from within a C program using `CreateProcess()`. If I am correct in guessing the problem, is there any way to ensure the program has the right directory for itself?

the main method of bezier.exe:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
char buf[200];
FILE* f = fopen("out.txt","w");
GetCurrentDirectory(200,buf);
fprintf(f,buf);
fclose(f);

SDL_Surface* screen;
SDL_Event e;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_FULLSCREEN|SDL_HWSURFACE);
if (screen == NULL)
    exit(-1);
SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);

srand(time(NULL));

loadColors(COLOR_FILE);

fill(screen, backColor);
initialiseVars();

while (e.type != SDL_KEYDOWN)
{
        //do stuff
}

SDL_Quit();
return 0;
```

}

Here's the crazy part. With "..> folder\bezier.exe" it doesn't write its path, but it does start a new window. That doesn't make any sense to me, because SDL_SetVideoMode is after writing the path.

Comment: I tried running bezier.exe on my linux server and it did not work? :-) How about providing some source code all us old school developers like reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetModuleHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out where your execuatble file is, then use that information to create a file specification for your local settings file.

`GetModuleHandle` with a NULL argument will give you the handle for the current executable. Then, passing that to `GetModuleFileName` will give you the fully qualified name of that executable. Just strip off the executable filename from the end and add your configuration file name.

However, that's been a bad idea for a *long* time now, since Windows provides per-application and per-user settings areas for this sort of stuff - you can generally get those locations with [`SHGetFolderLocation()` and its brethren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Use the first method only if this is for a personal project. If you plan to release your software to the wild, you should separate executable and configuration information as per Microsoft guidelines.

---

Regardless of that, it appears you now have the problem that you think the file is not being written to. You need to check that. When you open that file `out.txt` for write, it does so in the *current* directory. If you're running in the parent directory (with `folder\bezier.exe`), it will create it in the parent directory and looking for it in the `folder` directory is a waste of time.

If you *are* looking in the directory where you're running the program from, and it's still not being created, there are possible reasons for this. For a start, you should check (ie, capture and output) the return codes from *all* those `f*` functions, `fopen`, `fprintf` and `fclose`.

Comment: ... or, even better, he could just have his program accept the home of the settings via an argument :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I do not have those function on Linux or Aix or Solaris or VMS :-)

Comment: @Adrian, I'm not sure that's relevant. The `CreateProcess` call, backslashes for directory separators, and `.exe` extensions all seem to indicate a Windows app. Oops, hang on, I've just seen your smiley. Boy, do I feel stupid now? :-) I'll add the tag to the Q.

Comment: @paxdiablo I see someone added a windows tag now :-) and you are the last edit - could not resist a jibe at my fellows

Comment: I used the GetModuleFileName and it returned what it was supposed to both times, whatever\folder\. So the problem isnt that I can't find my settings file. I posted some of the source to my original. Excuse me if it is a bit ugly, this is a tiny little personal project.

Comment: Hmm nevermind. So this doesn't make any sense. From the command line, if I type "..folder> bezier.exe" it works fine, but if I type "..> folder\bezier.exe" it starts to open a new window but then exits. I posted the actual relevant code now. Soory about all that.